# ANGULAR 7 - No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { GlobalDataSummary } from '../models/global-data';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataServiceService {

  private globalDataUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/12-31-2020.csv';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
  getGlobalData(){
    return this.http.get(this.globalDataUrl, {responseType : 'text'}).pipe(
      map(res => {
        const data: GlobalDataSummary[] = [];
        const raw = {};
        const rows = res.split('\n');
        rows.splice(0, 1);
        rows.forEach(row => {
          const cols = row.split(/,(?=\S)/);

          const cs = {
            country : cols[3],
            confirmed : +cols[7],
            deaths : +cols[7],
            recovered : +cols[7],
            active : +cols[7]
          };


          const temp: GlobalDataSummary = raw[cs.country];
          if (temp){
            temp.active = cs.active + temp.active;
            temp.confirmed = cs.active + temp.confirmed;
            temp.deaths = cs.active + temp.deaths;
            temp.recovered = cs.active + temp.recovered;

            raw[cs.country] = temp;

          }else{
            raw[cs.country] = cs;
          }

        });
        console.log(raw);
        return [];
      })
      );
  }
}
```

At this part It says  **Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.**

```
const temp: GlobalDataSummary = raw[cs.country];
```

And In this part gives this error **Object is possibly 'undefined'.**

```
  temp.active = cs.active + temp.active;
 temp.confirmed = cs.active + temp.confirmed;
   temp.deaths = cs.active + temp.confirmed;
   temp.recovered = cs.active + temp.confirmed;
```

[image]
How can I solve this problem,
I am new at typescript and angular.

Comment: Either you can define a type for your "raw" variable or use any.

Comment: What about "Object is possibly 'undefined'" ```only gives that error    temp.active = cs.active + temp.active; ```at this part "+ temp.active; "

Comment: Either disabled "strictNullChecks" in tsConfig or check for null condition before assigning

Comment: share your GlobalDataSummary  model . with any type for the temp i am not getting any problem const temp: any = raw[cs.country]; .stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dgjqtq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: export interface GlobalDataSummary{
  country ?: string ;
  confirmed ?: number ;
  deaths ?: number ;
  recovered ?: number ;
  active ?: number;
}

Comment: ```const temp: GlobalDataSummary | undefined | null = raw[cs.country];``` I did this but still give me same error